# Hide terminal window using applescript

Tags: applescript

The purpose of the current snippet is to run a script in a new terminal window and instantly hide it. The code below initially seems to work fine but as a result, if the window is manipulated using its visible property it simply disappears and doesn't seem to be executing. Right clicking on the **`Terminal`** app within the **`Dock`** displays like there is no terminal window at all.

```
tell application "Terminal"

    -- New Terminal Window
    set newTab to do script "caffeinate -u -t 900"
    set caffeinateWindow to id of front window

    tell window id caffeinateWindow
        set index to 1
        set visible to false
    end tell

end tell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of telling the terminal use applesripts builtin possibilities:

```
do shell script "caffeinate -u -t 900"
```

if you ever want to pass parameters then do it like this:

```
set param to "900"
do shell script "caffeinate -u -t " & param
```

Note if a parameter might contain spaces you need to escape/quote it like this:

```
set param to "900"
do shell script "caffeinate -u -t " & quoted form of param
```

if you still need to hide a window do it like so:

```
tell application "System events"
    try 
        set visible of application process  "Terminal" to false
    end try
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Pat_Morita I will take them into consideration. There is one thing I didn't mention that sometimes I work with using active Terminal window and would like to hide only particular window that executes coffeinate :)

Comment: I changed a wrong piece of code. If the answer is correct for you please accept it so other with the same issue may find a solution too. glad i could help

Comment: Actually few mins later I realized that your first suggestion to use built-in options totally satisfies the logic since it doesn't open terminal window, so there is no need to further bother :D

Comment: Thank you, once again, man. Hope others will find this useful, too :)